# How to download source code of website after having emulated a button click?

Tags: c#, .net, browser, webclient

With WebClient I can download the source code.

> WebClient.DownloadString(url);

With WebBrowser I can emulate mouse click, getting the HTML element by Id and invoking it.

> WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("commit").InvokeMember("click");

My question is: How can I mix these to:

1. Press the button (one time or multiple times, the id remains unchanged).
2. Download updated source code (after button click).

P.S. As you can guess the button is a "View more" button that loads new elements, and the url stays the same all the time, there is no page 2. That's why I have a problem.

P.S. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695913/how-to-get-source-code-after-simulate-web-page-button-click-in-code) looks like my problem, but in my case it's the same page, not a new window

Comment: Why don't you just use AJAX in a framework like jQuery?

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about, I'm ignorant, but I will do some research, thank you.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester I didn't search a lot but I discovered that the button itself is submitting an AJAX command! This one: "$.ajax({complete:function(request){More.complete()}, data:$.param($(this).serializeArray()) + '&authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('ta55EgL5SY8W0B6ygmG0N6mgO2ueub40qa0xaj8c6Ok='), dataType:'script', type:'post', url:'/AriannaLonghin/more'}); Forms.More.afterSubmit(); return false;" Can you get something out of it? The test page is [this one](http://ask.fm/AriannaLonghin). (All Ask.fm profiles are public so that's not a problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me tell you that it makes no sense to use the `WebBrowser` and `WebClient` in conjunction like that. The `WebBrowser` is not an abstraction of the `WebClient` or anything like that, they are *completely* different and they are completely separate.

Assuming you want to persue this problem using the `WebBrowser`, you could download the page source using the `WebBrowser` component like so:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("commit").InvokeMember("click");
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (o, args) =>
{
    string pageSource = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
};
```

Comment: I knew it was confusing and stupid, but I didn't know any other solution. I'm trying your solution right now.

Comment: Your code was working but I discovered that somehow it was triggering the wrong button (same ID? my fault anyway), so I tried with another similar way, and it worked: [The class option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150610/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-with-the-webbrowser-control). Thank you, you helped me finding the solution. Now I have another problem, it won't work twice! If I put those invokations in a clickButton event it works everytime I click, but it won't work if I put it in a for loop. I tried to Thread.Sleep(1000) every cycle to make it run better, but it's not working.

Comment: @Neflux Please mark this answer as the accepted answer if it answers *this* question and then ask *another* question (with a code sample) relating to this new issue.